# Session_Start & Session_End in Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

To which events of which class do these 2 event handlers belong?

For instance **Application_BeginRequest** in **Global.asax** is registered to BeginRequest of HttpApplication class by naming convention.

I couldn't find anything in these 3 classes regarding those 2 session events:
**HttpApplication**, **HttpContext**, **HttpSessionState**

Comment: Why would they have to belong to a class? They're magic methods called by the ASP.NET runtime anyway.

Comment: The have to be registered to an event of a class somehow.

Comment: @CodeCaster - they're not magic. There's a specific mechanism by which you (or I) can register modules that would be treated identically by the runtime.

Comment: @Damien I meant that ASP.NET does reflection to find those methods and hook up the event handlers. You don't have to register the events yourself. Of course they are implemented in a class somewhere, but you don't have to know which one.

Comment: @CodeCaster - you do if you want to read the *documentation* for the events, to understand when they're called, for instance. We often get bad questions on here where people haven't read the documentation but if you're just treating the global.asax event handlers as "magic", you won't know where to *find* the documentation.

Comment: @Damien yeah I blame the lack of coffee. What was unclear to me was what exactly the OP was looking for: how the runtime calls or hooks up those methods, where the event raising code resides ("which class") or where the documentation for said events is. This would affect the way answers will be written. I was so far unable to express that in the above comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They belong to the [`SessionStateModule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule(v=vs.110).aspx).

It's old documentation, but if you start at [Using Modules with the Global.asax File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa735627(v=vs.71).aspx) you'll see that the events you can subscribe to are exposed by types that implement the `IHttpModule` interface. And looking at the documentation for [that interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule(v=vs.71).aspx), you'll find the built-in types that implement `IHttpModule`:

```
Class                         Description
DefaultAuthenticationModule   Insures that an Authentication object is present in the context. This class cannot be inherited.
FileAuthorizationModule       Verifies that the remote user has NT permissions to access the file requested. This class cannot be inherited.
FormsAuthenticationModule     Enables ASP.NET applications to use forms authentication. This class cannot be inherited.
PassportAuthenticationModul   Provides a wrapper around PassportAuthentication services. This class cannot be inherited.
SessionStateModule            Provides session-state services for an application.
UrlAuthorizationModule        Provides URL-based authorization services for allowing or denying access to specified resources. This class cannot be inherited.
WindowsAuthenticationModule   Enables ASP.NET applications to use Windows/IIS authentication. This class cannot be inherited.
```